# When analyzing a Java heap with jmap, how should I interpret empty survivor spaces?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm investigating why my Java application reaches a state of continously doing Full GC. In my opinion, the Old Generation space should not fill up, but it is continously maxed out. In [Oracle's GC tuning guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html), I stumbled over the sentence

> If survivor spaces are too small, copying collection overflows directly into the tenured generation.

so I wanted to see what those are doing and they are both empty (0 bytes used). I'm not sure how to read this. At what times should I expect data in there? How do I know if they are "overflowing into the tenured generation"? What if there's not enough space either?

Comment: Could you write which parameters are passed to the JVM, and which parameters are used with jmap?

Answer (score 0):

Survivor spaces are not big enough to hold objects moved from Eden space on partial GC. Their increase may result in less frequent full GC. Try different values for:

```
-XX:SurvivorRatio=16
```

16 is default value for WebSphere for example.